# 「。。。個人を超えた大きなものの」ってどういう意味ですか？

Tags: grammar

> 「。。。なるほど個人がひとつきりの体でその人生を生き、それを指して「わたし」と言いながらも全部がわたしと感じるゆえに「このわたし」**なんてものは個人を超えた大きなものの**、やっぱり一瞬間でしかないような気持ちにさせられます」

（川上未映子『世界クッキー』文藝春秋）

質問１：この「なんてものは」は「なんというものは」の省略ですか？

質問２：タイトルの通り、「個人を超えた大きなものの」はどういう意味ですか？
自分が習った文法では、「ものの」は「だが」の意味です。だから「個人を超えたものの」だけでも十分ではないかという疑問を持っています。「大きな」は何を表しているですか？

教えてください。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

質問1:

どちらかといえば「～なんていうものは」の省略かと思います。

意味は、”Things like ~”

質問2:

非常に哲学的な文章ですね。
全文を読んだわけではないので、拡大解釈をしますと…

まず、この「ものの」の直後にある濁点「、」ですが意味的な区切りを表しているのではなく、恐らく、読みやすさのためのものでしょう。

> ～個人を超えた大きなものの、やっぱり一瞬間～

の部分ですが、これは

「大きなものの一瞬」

とつながります。

ここで、一瞬の直前に「やっぱり」を挿入すると非常に読みづらくなるので、句読点を挿入したと考えられます。

つまり、質問者さんの言う「だが」の意味ではなく、「大きなものの一部」といった用法です。

”A part of a large thing”

さて、簡単のため、「やっぱり」を抜き文章を書きなおしますと…

> 「このわたし」なんてものは個人を超えた大きなものの一瞬間でしかないような気持ちにさせられます。

個別にみていきます。

> 個人を超えた大きなもの

この部分は「宇宙、地球、人類もしくは歴史」と解釈できます。

つまり、「このわたし」は個人を超えたもの（宇宙、歴史）の一瞬（宇宙から見れば刹那）でしかないような気持ち、と解釈できます。

ここで、省いた「やっぱり」ですが、「一瞬」の直前に配置することで、自身のちっぽけさを「再認識」しているのでしょう。

Comment: 教えてくださってありがとうございます。中略した部分の内容は、作者が銭湯で育たれ、毎日、様々な裸が見られるから、自分の体が変化していると考えているというような話である。@Sophian さんの解釈で読むと筋が通っていますね。

Comment: 補足ありがとうございます。非常に興味深いですね。気になるので、原文をインターネット上で可能な限り調べてみました。『全部がわたしと感じる』という部分は、直前の『そこにあるたくさんの体がすべて自分の体である、繫がっているのだと思えてくる』を指しているのでしょう。さらに@JoisBackさんの説明してくださった『自分の体が変化している』という時間的な解釈を考えれば、この『個人を超えた大きなもの』というのは、『人類』もしくは時間的な意味が加わった『過去、未来含めた人類』というように捉える事ができると思います。一つの体に閉じ込められた「このわたし」というのは、人類の歴史の刹那でしかない…。この事実を銭湯での生活を通して、感じたのでしょう。

Answer (score 3):

Some additional notes:

In real-life usage, the phrase "~なんてものは" –  as well as its other variants –  is often followed by "所詮(しょせん)" or "所詮~に過ぎない".

> {e.g.}: 愛**なんてものは** / **などというのは** / etc、**所詮**幻想**に過ぎない**。

---

Nuance-wise, the phrase "~なんてものは (所詮~に過ぎない)" has a (self-)deprecating/depreciating connotation of:

> (**When it's all said and done**), I can't help but feel like *I* am **nothing but** a tiny, insignificant speck – a leaf in the storm – in the great scheme of things, living a fleeting moment in the eternal flow of time.

```
「このわたし」なんてものは個人を超えた大きなものの、やっぱり一瞬間でしかないような気持ちにさせられます。
```

Answer (score 1):

> 質問１：この「なんてものは」は「なんというものは」の省略ですか？

この「なんて」の「なん」は、「[何]{なに}」ではなく、「**など**」が音便化したものです。

「～なんて」 ＜＜ 副助詞「**など**」＋ 格助詞「とて」

cf. 「なんて」（何て） ＜＜ なんという ＜＜ **なに**という（何+と+言う）

ですので、「『このわたし』なんてものは」は、「『このわたし』**などという**ものは」と言い換えることができます。

この「～なんて」や「～などという」は、取り上げるものを**軽んじていう気持ち**を表しています。この場合は「このわたし」を軽んじて取り上げています。

> 質問２：タイトルの通り、「個人を超えた大きなものの」はどういう意味ですか？ 自分が習った文法では、「ものの」は「だが」の意味です。だから「個人を超えたものの」だけでも十分ではないかという疑問を持っています。「大きな」は何を表しているですか？

あなたの習った「ものの」は、接続助詞としての用法です。

今回の「ものの」は、名詞「もの（物）」＋格助詞「の」です。

先の回答者さんが仰るように、

> 「このわたし（などというもの）は、個人を超えた大きなものの（やはり）一瞬間でしかない」

という構文です。

本文を読んでいないのではっきりわかりませんが、この「大きなもの」は、「宇宙」「世界」「永遠」「人類全体」のような、そんな感じの「自分が属する大きな存在」を指しているのかな、と思います。

Comment: ＠Chocolate さん、丁寧に説明してくださってありがとうございます。「など」の省略と「とて」という格助詞は知りませんでした。とても勉強になりました。