# appending なんて to a verb

Tags: word-choice

なんて is the て form of なの. What is the difference when using なんて and without. For example:

こんなにつまんないような大人になる**なんて**思いもしなかった

こんなにつまんないような大人に**なって**思いもしなかった

こんなにつまんないような大人**になるって**思いもしなかった

Answer (score 3):

> なんて is the て form of なの.

No, the なんて is an adverbial particle (副助詞) [「なんて」](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%A6-590615), derived from 副助詞「など」+ 格助詞「と/とて」. Here's a [related thread](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/60107/9831).

---

> こんなにつまんない<s>ような</s>大人になる**なんて**思いもしなかった。

つまんない**ような**大人 sounds unnatural.
The use of なんて is correct and natural. It can be replaced with とは or などとは, as in:

> こんなにつまらない大人になる**とは**思いもしなかった。
>   こんなにつまらない大人になる**などとは**思いもしなかった。

などとは = など+と+は. The は is here because of the negative なかった.

<sub>Colloquial つま**ん**ない (cf. つま**ら**ない) would go better with colloquial なんて than rather formal とは or などとは.</sub>

> こんなにつまんない<s>ような</s>大人に**なって**思いもしなかった。

is incorrect. The 大人になって would mean "I became an adult, and...", so 思いもしなかった "I didn't even imagine (that... would...)" wouldn't make much sense. 思いもしなかった needs to follow 「[sentence] + とは / なんて / などとは」.

> こんなにつまんない<s>ような</s>大人になる**って**思いもしなかった。

would make sense and can be used in colloquial speech, but it's more natural/correct to use 「なんて」「などとは」「とは」 here.