# Meaning of のs in this sentence

Tags: manga, parsing

The below sentence is inner thoughts produced by the guy going out with a hot girl (from manga). I get a general idea but I am not sure about its grammar.

> 俺みたいな**の**に、付き合ってる**の**、なんて時間の無駄くらいに思ってて、当然なのに...

I wonder if the first の is a normalizer for 人. Also, I am not sure about the particle に with the verb 付き合う. It is supposed to be と.

What is the second の is doing? I think it is redundant because of なんて?

Maybe I am parsing the whole sentence wrong. There are two のにs in this sentence meaning although. The second の is normalizer and なんて means something like なんといっても.

> 俺みたいなのに... 付き合ってるのはなんて時間の無駄くらいに思ってて当然なのに...

But I am still not sure about 俺みたいなのに. Why it can't be 俺なのに.

Comment: Those commas look fairly unnatural to me. Is this guy speaking very slowly for some reason, or did *you* insert them in place of line breaks?

Comment: @naruto yes, they represent line breaks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- A**と**付き合う and A**に**付き合う are both valid expressions. A**と**付き合う tends to mean "to date A" (A and the subject are in a romantic relationship). On the other hand, A**に**付き合う does not assume a romantic relationship, and it's often more natural to translate it like "to keep A company", "to go out with A (for a practical purpose)", "to spend time with A", "to socialize with A" or even "to play along with A".
- The first の after 俺みたいな is a substitute for 人. There is no のに meaning "although" at this position.
- The second の after 付き合ってる is a nominalizer that turns 付き合う into a noun. なんて can take both a verb and a noun, so this の is optional, but this の doesn't feel redundant to me.
- 俺なのに ("although it is me") makes no sense here.

> 俺みたいなのに付き合ってるのなんて時間の無駄(だ)くらいに思ってて当然なのに...
>
> It's only natural if she thinks it's a waste of time to socialize with a person like me, but...

Comment: Thank you for your answers! @sundowner you too!

Answer (score 2):

Grammatically the following should answer your question.

- [How exactly are 準体助詞 and 形式名詞 different? In what regard? And where does の stand?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/93338/45489)

Also regarding なんて, you can see

- [appending なんて to a verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/74825/45489)

---

The sentence without using の should be something like

- 俺みたいな**やつ**に付き合ってる**こと**なんて時間の無駄くらいに思ってて、当然なのに

which literally means

- It should be natural that (the subj.) think it is a waste of time **to** go out with **a guy** like me.

The first の is a substitute for やつ and the second is a nominalizer.